# Is there a way to further group these query results by overall time?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query in Postgres which shows the peak time for a QR Code scan each day. Is it possible to further group this so it shows the peak time overall? Below is the current query and some example results. I'd like to get these results to show that 01:00 is the peak time overall.

```
select count(*), date_trunc('hour', created_at) 
from code_scans 
group by date_trunc('hour', created_at)
order by count desc;
```

Results:

```
| count | date_trunc             |
| ----- | ---------------------- |
| 5     | 2024-01-11 01:00:00+00 |
| 4     | 2024-01-17 00:00:00+00 |
| 2     | 2024-01-16 18:00:00+00 |
| 2     | 2024-01-12 01:00:00+00 |
```

Comment: Is this not just the first row? You already have “order by count desc” which is all you need

Comment: Well now I feel stupid :D Of course that works! Thank you very much.